# TraceInformation method call is disabled by compiler

Tags: c#, .net, breakpoints, tracesource

I put a breakpoint to the last line of code. Breakpoint is disabled. Why?
It looks like the code is excluded by some condition. The constructor of TraceSource works, and I can verify the object is OK and all listeners are OK. It really looks bizarre. I stop on int a=1; and then debugger skips TraceInformation by ignoring it. The configuration is DEBUG x86.

```
public TraceSource _fixTraceSource;

_fixTraceSource = new TraceSource(_configSection.TraceSourceName);

int a = 1; // dummy line to set breakpoint
_fixTraceSource.TraceInformation("FIX -> toAdmin Message: {0}", message.ToString());
```

Comment: Did you a fully recompile and set configuration to Debug and did you include debugging information in project settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TraceInformation` is marked:

```
[Conditional("TRACE")]
```

So you need the `TRACE` symbol defined **at compile time** for it to be included. This is usually by checking the "Define TRACE constant" box in the project properties page (it is enabled by default for both Debug and Release profiles, so somebody has *unchecked* it at some point).